# how do i set onclick event within innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to use innerHTML to insert some data into an html page like folowing

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
var line = data[i].split("~");

nameslist.innerHTML += '<p onClick='+userclick(line[1])+'><strong>' + line[0] + ' </strong></p>';

}
```

but onclick event fired automatically directly after the insert and it wont fire when i click on the `<p>` element

how do i use innerhtml properly to add a p element with onclick event and fire it only when user click ?

Comment: You are calling the function, not assigning the content to the attribute. Just put it within the string. `'<p onClick="userclick(line[1])">`

Comment: *Don't*!. Mashing together strings to generate JS embedded in HTML inside a JS program is a *nightmark*. Use DOM methods like `createElement`, `appendChild` and `addEventListener` instead. It's more verbose but **much** easier to maintain.

Comment: I think this will depend on what flavor of ES you need to be using in terms of using template strings or arrow functions. You can always use `setAttribute` afterward. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: `<p>` elements aren't designed to be interactive. You can add a click event handler to them, but then someone comes along and can't use a mouse but they can't focus the `<p>` because it isn't designed to be a UI control. Use appropriate elements (e.g. `<button>`).

Comment: ooh that's a good point @Quentin

Comment: @rpivovar - `setAttribute` is part of the DOM standard, not EcmaScript. Using that in combination with `innerHTML` is going to be … difficult. First you have to get hold of a reference to the new element …

Comment: True -- it wouldn't be elegant, but it would work

Comment: @Quentin tried button also it wont fire `nameslist.innerHTML += '<button onclick="userclick(' + line[1] + ')"><strong>' + line[0] + ' </strong></button>';`

Comment: @DelphiStudent — Read my first comment. You haven't followed the advice I gave there. (You also haven't provided a [mcve])

Comment: @Quentin fine i will work with event listener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are willing to take a different approach you could add an event listener to a parent node and let the click event bubble up to the parent.

An example can be found here:
https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

```
// Get the element, add a click listener...
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // e.target is the clicked element!
    // If it was a list item
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        // List item found!  Output the ID!
        console.log("List item ", e.target.id.replace("post-", ""), " was clicked!");
    }
});
```

Comment: i accept this answer sense its refer to using event listener as @Quentin commented out